# List elements less than tolerance in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a list `Test` containing numpy arrays. I want to see if each array element is less than the `tol` value. If it is less, it should return empty list. But I am getting an error. I present the expected output.

```
import numpy as np
tol=1e-12
Test=[[np.array([9.75016872e-15])], [np.array([9.75016872e-15]), np.array([0.00019793]), np.array([0.0001007])]]

for i in range(0,len(Test)):
    for j in range(0,len(Test[i])): 
        if (Test[j][i]<tol): 
            Test[j][i]=[] 
        else: 
            Test=Test[j][i]
print(Test)
```

The error is

```
in <module>
    if (CB[j][i]<tol):

IndexError: list index out of range
```

The expected output is

```
[[[]], [[], array([0.00019793]), array([0.0001007])]]
```

Comment: should it be Test[i][j] instead of Test[j][i] ?
Also, you don't need any else statement, and modifying a list while iterating over it can lead to strange behaviour, try to avoid such code.

Comment: could you have more than 1 number in a deepermost array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about a list comprehension?

```
out = [[[] if (a<tol).all() else a for a in l] for l in Test]

# [[[]], [[], array([0.00019793]), array([0.0001007])]]
```

Fix of your code:

```
for i in range(len(Test)):
    for j in range(len(Test[i])): 
        if Test[i][j] < tol:
            Test[i][j] = []
```

Comment: Are the starting indices for the ranges even necessary?

Comment: @BRemmelzwaal not at all, I just copied OP's code and fixed the error ;)